# UserControl in Windows Phone 8.x project can't be found: "The type or namespace name 'UserControls' does not exist in the namespace"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, user-controls, visual-studio-2015, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

I have a windows phone project where I've added a usercontrol:

```
namespace MyApp.WindowsPhone.UserControls
{
    public partial class SlidingUpOverlay : UserControl
    {
        public SlidingUpOverlay()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
       }
    }
}
```

Then I'm referencing it in a Page like this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="MyApp.WindowsPhone.UI.TopUpPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:MyApp.WindowsPhone.UserControls">



<userControls:SlidingUpOverlay x:Name="SlidingUpOverlay" Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

But building it gives me following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'UserControls' does not exist in the namespace 'MyApp.WindowsPhone.MyApp.WindowsPhone' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    MyApp-WP C:\Users\MyApp\developers\apps\MyApp-WP\MyApp-WP\obj\Debug\UI\TopUpPage.g.i.cs
```

I've cleaned bin and obj-folders, restarted computer, restarted VS2015, tried everything suggested but nothing works. I've also read through many pages here on stackoverflow but haven't found anything the suggests anything else than I've already tried. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:MyApp.WindowsPhone.UserControls"
```

You could try changing this line to:

```
xmlns:userControls="using:MyApp.WindowsPhone.UserControls"
```

Comment: It won't accept that. userControls:SlidingUpOverlay becomes red and suggests to import 

    xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:MyApp.WindowsPhone.UserControls"

and I'm back to square one... :(

Answer (score 0):

Change the namespace of user control:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class SlidingUpOverlay : UserControl
    {
        public SlidingUpOverlay()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
       }
    }
}
```

Then add the following reference in your Xaml Page:

```
xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:MyApp">
```

P.S. Also change the Xaml schema of your User control

```
x:Class="MyApp.SlidingUpOverlay"
```

Comment: Nope, that don't work either. What's weird is that it is the g.i.cs file that generates the wrong namespace, not the g.cs file. When I look at the g.cs it shows: internal MyApp.SlidingUpOverlay SlidingUpOverlay;

Comment: I.e. the error states: The type or namespace name 'SlidingUpOverlay' does not exist in the namespace 'MyApp.WindowsPhone.MyApp' (are you missing an assembly reference?) MyApp-WP C:\Users\MyApp\developers\pernilla\apps\MyApp-WP\MyApp-WP\obj\Debug\UI\TopUpPage.g.cs  46  , which looks really weird (the namespace).

Comment: can you show me the schemas you added on usercontrol Xaml ?